# How to have Excel update automatically based on CSV

Tags: excel, csv

I have CSV files that will be getting automatically updated with data from another program.

In the same directory will be xlsx files with the same information.  What is the best way to ensure that the updated data from the CSV automatically matches the xlsx whenever I have to open the xlsx in Excel?

The reason I can't just use CSV is because the xlsx has a custom graphical header that needs to get printed along with the data.

Comment: Import it and create a connection?  [See here](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Connect-external-data-to-your-workbook-945f2cbb-d50b-4ee2-bae8-c4c9381000c6)

Comment: I'm dealing with a lot of excel files though.  Is there an automatic way to do this?

Comment: you could automate the process of creating the Excel files and/or inserting the connection using VBA